# Qt делегаты и условное форматирование

Tags: c++, qt, делегаты

Нужно создать делегат для столбца в таблице, который меняет цвет фона в ячейке по цветовой шкале от самого большого значения (тёмно-зелёный) до самого маленького (тёмно-красный). В Excel'e это выглядит так:
[image: Пример]

Comment: Для того, чтобы определить цвет ячейки нужно оперировать всеми данными. ИМХО, разумнее будет делать это на уровне модели, т.к. делегат все же использует одно значение

Answer (score 1):

Так а сам вопрос-то в чём? Нужно создавать делегат - создавай.
Если нужно поменять цвет фона в ячейке таблицы, то это делается примерно так:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
...
item->setText(QString::number(...));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(r, c, item);
// цвет ячейки надо менять после того, как ячейку установили
ui->tableWidget->item(r, c)->setBackground(QColor(...));
...
```

Comment: Данные в таблице могут меняться и в зависимости от этих данных должен меняться цвет ячейки. 1 раз раскрасить и забыть не вариант

Comment: ну так это и вызывается каждый раз при смене данных.  разве тут кто-то сказал, что только один раз?  ей-богу, непонятно в чём вопрос.  может, стоит научиться формулировать чётко свои хотелки?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
class Model : public QAbstractItemModel{
    struct Item{
        int value;
        QColor color;
        Item(int value = 0,
             const QColor &color = QColor()):
            value(value),
            color(color),
        {}
    };
    struct ToPointer{
        Item* operator()(Item &item) const{
            return &item;
        }
    };
    struct LessValue{
        bool operator()(Item *first, Item *second) const{
            return first->value < second->value;
        }
    };
    QVector<Item> _items;

    void _updateColors(){  
        QVector<Item*> items(_items.size());
        std::transform(_items.begin(), _items.end(), items, ToPointer());
        std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), LessValue());
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i){
            items[i]->color = indexToColor(i);
        }

        QModelIndex topLeft = index(0, 0);
        QModelIndex bottomRight = index(items.size(), 0);
    }
public:
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const{
        //...

        if(role == Qt::BackgroundRole){
            return QBrush(_items[index.row()].color);
        }

        //...
    }
};
```

Данные и цвета хранятся в вместе, каждый раз когда данные в модели меняются нужно вызывать `_updateColors()`, чтобы обновить цвета.

**PS**: Я не стал ломать голову над тем как реализовать метод `indexToColor`. Это тема для отдельного вопроса.

Comment: Проблема в том, что такое форматирование должно использоваться только в одном столбце, поэтому размещение этого в модели я считал слегка некорректным